# PyQt5 GUI for android vs Kivy GUI

Tags: android, python, kivy, pyqt5, python-3.7

I need to know help on which is more efficient to do. This is my situation I already have a GUI using PyQt programmed for windows I want it to be also installed on an android phone. Should I find away to packaged(through pyqtdeploy or any other means) to android or make another similar GUI with same functionalities using Kivy because its much more android friendly?

Answer (score 1):

For now, I think you should learn ***Kivy*** because ***pyqtdeploy*** is a young project. The Dev team still working on it to fix some bugs.

But in the future, **if pyqtdeploy become efficient**, it will be the best choice ! 
PyQt5 has many incredible widgets and you use also *QML* to design more advanced interface for mobile devices (Android & iOS).